# Using .addClass in a dynamic way

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDITED:**

I'm using Jquery to display 1 message at a time, from multiple possible messages (could be just one, or two, or 3 or more), every 10 seconds - It will depend on whether certain conditions are being met for each `$i` item (I will have multiple items):

```
    <div class="mszDivOuter">
               <?php if ($condition1[$i]==true) { ?>
                  <div class="mszDiv activeMsz">message 1</div>
               <?php } else { } ?> 
               <?php if ($condition2[$i]==true) { ?>
                  <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 2</div>
               <?php } else { } ?> 
               <?php if ($condition3[$i]==true) { ?>
                  <div class="mszDiv deactiveMsz">message 3</div>
               <?php } else { } ?> 
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){ 
        jQuery(".mszDivOuter").each(function(){
            var cnt = crActiveMsz = nextMszNum = 0; 
            cnt = $(this).children('.mszDiv').length;
            if(cnt > 1){
                crActiveMsz = $(this).children('.activeMsz').index();
                nextMszNum = crActiveMsz + 2;

                if(nextMszNum > cnt){ nextMszNum = 1;}

                $(this).children('.mszDiv').removeClass("activeMsz");
                $(this).children('.mszDiv').addClass("deactiveMsz");

                $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').removeClass("deactiveMsz");
                $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').addClass("activeMsz");
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.mszDiv{ position:absolute; transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); -0-transform: translateY(-50%); top:50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); top:50%;}
 .activeMsz{ opacity:1;
 -webkit-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -moz-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -o-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    -ms-animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
    animation: slide-down 1s linear ;
 }
 .deactiveMsz{ opacity:0;}
```

The problem:

When the first message doesn't have `activMsz` class, it will remain blank for the first 10 seconds, and only then will start toggling between other messages.

To avoid the waiting time, I tried using a different JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  switchMsg();
  setInterval(switchMsg, 10000);
});

function switchMsg() {
    jQuery(".mszDivOuter").each(function(){
        var cnt = crActiveMsz = nextMszNum = 0; 
        cnt = $(this).children('.mszDiv').length;
        if(cnt > 1){
            crActiveMsz = $(this).children('.activeMsz').index();
            nextMszNum = crActiveMsz + 2;

            if(nextMszNum > cnt){ nextMszNum = 1;}

            $(this).children('.mszDiv').removeClass("activeMsz");
            $(this).children('.mszDiv').addClass("deactiveMsz");

            $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').removeClass("deactiveMsz");
            $(this).children('.mszDiv:nth-child('+nextMszNum+')').addClass("activeMsz");
        }
    });
}
```

But with this code, in some cases some of the messages simply will not show up at all.

How to modify the code in order to show all possible messages, with no waiting, in each of the above HTML scenarios?

Edit 2:

**Desired behaviour:**
the first message from the HTML block (message 1, if it is included. message 2, if 1 is excluded by PHP, or message 3, if 1+2 are exluded by PHP). should show right away on screen, with no delay. then, they should switch to the next message after 10 seconds, if another message exists. if no

Comment: Not at all clear how the filtering should work to determine what should be shown and what shouldn't

Comment: basically I will loop on various items. each item may or may not fullfill a PHP conidition. if it does not fullfill it, the relevant message will not be shown.

Comment: php runs on server not in browser and that really doesn't clarify much

Comment: I know. I'm combining both methods.

Comment: But you are asking how to manage in browser using javascript. Confusing

Comment: I don't want to control the classes with PHP. with PHP I just want to control which "messages" will be inserted. Javascript should be the method to control how and when to display these messages.

Comment: Then provide a proper explanation of ***exactly*** how this is supposed to work. That is where the confusion is. If it was clear you would have had an answer long before now

Comment: Ok. I've edited the HTML block to make it exactly what it looks like.

Comment: So where is the properly detail explanation of expected behavior?

Comment: I've added desired behaviour to end of question.